# Parse String to Sql Datetime

Tags: java

I want to parse a String into a SQL DateTime. The string is the result of the concatenation of a SQL Date and a String that contains the time with the following format: HH:MM.

My code:

```
try {
        java.util.Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse(beanActividad.getFecha().toString() + " " + beanActividad.getHora() + ":00");
        datetime = new java.sql.Timestamp(date.getTime());
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ActividadesBackingBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

`beanActividad.getHora()` gets the hour String part, `beanActividad.getFecha().toString()` the java util Date part and finally it all concatenates with ":00", so it has a SQL DateTime properly syntax.

The error:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Tue May 26 00:00:00 CEST 2020 12:00:00"
```

What i want is to get a TimeStamp, so I can load it into the database as a SQL DateTime.

Answer (score 0):

You must define a formatting pattern to match your input precisely.  `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"` is not even close to matching `"Tue May 26 00:00:00 CEST 2020 12:00:00"`.

Tip: That input's format is a terrible choice for exchanging date-time values. I suggest you educate the publisher of your data regarding the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard.

I cannot show a formatting pattern to match your input. Your input example has two time-of-day values, contradictory. So the input is senseless, from what I can gather.

Another problem: You are using terrible date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

All this has been covered many many times on Stack Overflow. Search thoroughly before posting.